# yarn build "Cannot find name" error for typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx, yarnpkg-v3

I have the following .tsx component:

```
const Header = ({ dict: map, lang: string }) => {
  return (
    <header className="flex items-center justify-between py-10">
      <div>
        <Link href={`/${lang}`} aria-label={siteMetadata.headerTitle}>
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
          ...
```

yarn build is giving the following error when linting:
`Type error: Cannot find name 'lang'` referring to the href in the Link component. Why is this the case, when I have already passed in lang in the prop to the component?

Answer (score 1):

Is your define error?

> const Header = ({ dict: map, lang: string }) => {

I think it should be

```
const Header = ({dict, lang}: { dict: Map, lang: string }) => {
```

Comment: Doing this gives a different error:
```
Type error: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?
```

Comment: yeah, `Map` is right